# Site loading issue when using Cake in PHP 3.6

Tags: cakephp

Error:

> unlink(D:\xampp\htdocs\digitalstore/tmp/cache/models/myapp_cake_model_debug_kit_panels):
>   Permission denied [APP/Controller\AppController.php, line 304]

My code:

```
$base_path = ROOT . '/tmp';
$models      = $base_path.'/cache/models';
$persistent  = $base_path.'/cache/persistent';
$cache_files = array($models,$persistent);


//To delete Cache files
foreach ($cache_files as $filepath) {
    $filepath = $filepath.'/*';
    $files = glob($filepath); //get all file names
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(is_file($file)) {
            unlink($file); //delete file
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously: Read the error message. What's unclear about it? Also I assume you haven't bothered to read the docs: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#permissions

Comment: Seriously: I Can't Understand Could you explain it.. How to clear this problem. I dont Know where its use this...                            HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
setfacl -R -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx tmp
setfacl -R -d -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx tmp
setfacl -R -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx logs
setfacl -R -d -m u:${HTTPDUSER}:rwx logs

Comment: **Permission denied** says it all? The documentation also clearly tells you to run the above commands "**On a UNIX system**". You're *not reading* what I've linked. Since you're running windows use Google to figure out how to change permissions there. This is not a CakePHP problem at all by the way.